# .htaccess and RedirectPermanent - Mistyped URL - How to change it?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am experiencing an issue while using RedirectPermanent in the .htaccess file.

So let's suppose we want to redirect a user, using RedirectPermanent, from **/contact** to **/contact-me**.

```
RedirectPermanent /contact /contaxt-me
```

Oups! By mistake we typed **contaxt-me** instead of **contact-me**.

You say, I will change it to **contact-me** in **.htaccess** file and everything will be ok!
But it's **NOT**.

Even if I corrected, the Rewrite Rule, didn't change. I suppose that's it's somewhere stored on the server, but I can't figure out where!

What should I do?

Comment: Hi @Alessandro! If someone has answered your question remember to mark their answer as accepted rather than change the title of the question to include [SOLVED].

Answer (score 2):

It's not stored on the server, 90% of the time this is because your browser has the redirect cached. When your browser requests a URL, say `http://example.com/contact` and the response is a **301 Moved** with a new location, the browser will remember that `http://example.com/contact` has permanently moved to `http://example.com/contaxt-me`, so the next time you ask for `http://example.com/contact`, the browser will send you right to `/contaxt-me` without even going back to the server. This is sort of the point of having a permanent (301) redirect vs a temporary one (302).

Try to clear your browser's cache, or add an additional permanent redirect:

```
RedirectPermanent /contaxt-me /contact-me
```

You may want to do both if people or search engine indexing bots have already gone to `/contaxt-me` and indexed it.

Comment: What a noob! Oh my friend, you were right! Cache did the trick! I cleared the cache and it worked like a charm. I didn't think it before. Thanks man! :)